# How to use a variable before it is defined in self-defined likelihood function

Tags: python, scipy-optimize, simultaneous, log-likelihood

I am trying to estimate a self-defined likelihood function

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def lik(params):
    p_s = params[0]
    lamda_s=params[1]
    lamda_bl=params[2]
    phi_bl=params[3]
    p_hat=params[4]

    a1_bl = 4 * df["s1"] + 1 * df["s2"] + 6 * df["s3"]
    a2_bl = 0 * df["s1"] + 2 * df["s2"] + 8 * df["s3"]
    a3_bl = 10 * df["s1"] + 4 * df["s2"] + 0 * df["s3"]

    p1_bl = np.exp(lamda_bl*(a1_bl-a2_bl))/(np.exp(lamda_bl * (a1_bl - a2_bl))+1 + np.exp(lamda_bl*(a3_bl-a2_bl)))
    p2_bl = 1 / (np.exp(lamda_bl*(a1_bl-a2_bl))+1+np.exp(lamda_bl * (a3_bl-a2_bl)))
    p3_bl = np.exp(lamda_bl*(a3_bl-a2_bl))/(np.exp(lamda_bl * (a1_bl - a2_bl))+1 + np.exp(lamda_bl*(a3_bl-a2_bl)))

    df['f_bl'] = p1_bl*y1+p2_bl*y2+p3_bl*y3

    s1_s = p1_s * p_hat + p1_bl * (1- p_hat)
    s2_s = p2_s * p_hat + p2_bl * (1 - p_hat)
    s3_s = p3_s * p_hat + p3_bl * (1 - p_hat)

    a1_s = 4 * s1_s + 1 * s2_s + 6 * s3_s
    a2_s = 0 * s1_s + 2 * s2_s + 8 * s3_s
    a3_s = 10 * s1_s + 4 * s2_s + 0 * s3_s

    p1_s = np.exp(lamda_s*(a1_s-a2_s))/(np.exp(lamda_s * (a1_s - a2_s)) + 1 + np.exp(lamda_s*(a3_s-a2_s)))
    p2_s = 1 / (np.exp(lamda_s*(a1_s-a2_s))+1+np.exp(lamda_s * (a3_s-a2_s)))
    p3_s = np.exp(lamda_s*(a3_s-a2_s))/(np.exp(lamda_s * (a1_s - a2_s))+1 + np.exp(lamda_s*(a3_s-a2_s)))

    df['f_s'] = p1_s*y1+p2_s*y2+p3_s*y3

    pcodes = df["pcode"].unique()
    ff_bl = np.array([np.prod(df['f_bl'][df['pcode'] == i]) for i in pcodes])
    ff_s = np.array([np.prod(df['f_s'][df['pcode'] == i]) for i in pcodes])

    pp = p_s * ff_s + (1-p_s)*ff_bl

    li=np.log(pp)
    LL=np.sum(li)

    return -LL

results = minimize(lik,np.array([0.6, 0.6, 0.1, 0.3,0.2]),method= 'L-BFGS-B')
print(results)
```

`s1_s`, `a1_s` and `p1_s` are interdependent, and so I got an error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'p1_s' referenced before assignment`.

Is there a way to write such likelihood function without solving it myself?

Comment: What do you expect to do with a variable that points to no data?

Comment: I understand this point. So far I am just writing down the theoretical model. I am just wondering how I should proceed from here.

Comment: You can't define mutually recursive values like that in almost any programming language. Programming statements are evaluated in order in a way that makes doing so problematic. Note that *functions* actually *can* be mutually recursive, in a way *values* cannot, as long as the recursion is not infinite.

Comment: You should define you variables before you use them. That's how I would proceed from here.

Comment: There is a way to declare mutually dependent equations. I can demonstrate later.

Comment: Actually I can't without writing fake values because you haven't defined `y1`, `y2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add one of the variable series in your cyclic dependency as degrees of freedom, and then add a nonlinear constraint that tells the solver to optimize while holding the equality true.

There's a lot of code in your program that is either under-vectorised or mis-vectorised but I cannot help with most of it, because you're missing a pile of variables in your question and so I've had to fill in numerous ("bogus") gaps to make this reproducible. It's critical that you add reasonable bounds.

```py
from functools import partial

import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize, NonlinearConstraint, Bounds


def unpack_params(
    params: np.ndarray,
    s1: np.ndarray, s2: np.ndarray, s3: np.ndarray,
) -> tuple[float, ...]:
    (
        (p_s, lamda_s, lamda_bl, phi_bl, p_hat), p1_s, p2_s, p3_s,
    ) = np.split(params, (5, 5 + len(s1), 5 + 2*len(s1)))

    # inefficient
    a1_bl =  4*s1 + 1*s2 + 6*s3
    a2_bl =  0*s1 + 2*s2 + 8*s3
    a3_bl = 10*s1 + 4*s2 + 0*s3

    # inefficient
    denb = np.exp(lamda_bl*(a1_bl - a2_bl)) + 1 + np.exp(lamda_bl*(a3_bl - a2_bl))
    p1_bl = np.exp(lamda_bl*(a1_bl - a2_bl)) / denb
    p2_bl = 1 / denb
    p3_bl = np.exp(lamda_bl*(a3_bl - a2_bl)) / denb

    return p_s, lamda_s, lamda_bl, phi_bl, p_hat, p1_s, p2_s, p3_s, p1_bl, p2_bl, p3_bl


def likelihood(
    params: np.ndarray,
    s1: np.ndarray, s2: np.ndarray, s3: np.ndarray,
    y1: np.ndarray, y2: np.ndarray, y3: np.ndarray,
    pcode: np.ndarray,
) -> float:
    (
        p_s, lamda_s, lamda_bl, phi_bl, p_hat, p1_s, p2_s, p3_s, p1_bl, p2_bl, p3_bl,
    ) = unpack_params(params, s1, s2, s3)

    f_bl = p1_bl*y1 + p2_bl*y2 + p3_bl*y3
    f_s  = p1_s *y1 + p2_s *y2 + p3_s *y3

    # inefficient
    pcodes = np.unique(pcode)
    ff_bl = np.array([np.prod(f_bl[pcode == i]) for i in pcodes])
    ff_s  = np.array([np.prod(f_s [pcode == i]) for i in pcodes])

    pp = p_s*ff_s + (1 - p_s)*ff_bl

    li = np.log(pp)
    ll = li.sum()
    return -ll


def constrain_ps(
    s1: np.ndarray, s2: np.ndarray, s3: np.ndarray,
    params: np.ndarray,
) -> np.ndarray:
    (
        p_s, lamda_s, lamda_bl, phi_bl, p_hat, p1_s, p2_s, p3_s, p1_bl, p2_bl, p3_bl,
    ) = unpack_params(params, s1, s2, s3)

    # inefficient
    s1_s = p1_s*p_hat + p1_bl*(1 - p_hat)
    s2_s = p2_s*p_hat + p2_bl*(1 - p_hat)
    s3_s = p3_s*p_hat + p3_bl*(1 - p_hat)

    # inefficient
    a1_s =  4*s1_s + 1*s2_s + 6*s3_s
    a2_s =  0*s1_s + 2*s2_s + 8*s3_s
    a3_s = 10*s1_s + 4*s2_s + 0*s3_s

    # inefficient
    dens = np.exp(lamda_s * (a1_s - a2_s)) + 1 + np.exp(lamda_s*(a3_s-a2_s))
    p1_sv = np.exp(lamda_s*(a1_s - a2_s))/dens
    p2_sv = 1 / dens
    p3_sv = np.exp(lamda_s*(a3_s - a2_s))/dens

    # inefficient
    return np.concatenate((
        p1_sv - p1_s,
        p2_sv - p2_s,
        p3_sv - p3_s,
    ))


def solve(*args: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    s1, s2, s3, *_ = args

    result = minimize(
        fun=likelihood,  #             v BOGUS v
        x0=(0.6, 0.6, 0.1, 0.3, 0.2) + (0.5,)*(3*len(s1)),
        args=args,
        constraints=NonlinearConstraint(
            fun=partial(constrain_ps, s1, s2, s3),
            lb=0, ub=0,
        ),
        options={'maxiter': 1_000},
        bounds=Bounds(lb=0.1, ub=5),  # < BOGUS
    )
    assert result.success, result.message
    return result.x


def main() -> None:
    rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)
    s1, s2, s3, y1, y2, y3 = rand.random(size=(6, 10))  # < BOGUS
    pcode = rand.integers(low=0, high=10, size=10)      # < BOGUS

    params = solve(s1, s2, s3, y1, y2, y3, pcode)

    (
        p_s, lamda_s, lamda_bl, phi_bl, p_hat, p1_s, p2_s, p3_s, p1_bl, p2_bl, p3_bl,
    ) = unpack_params(params, s1, s2, s3)
    print('     p_s =', p_s)
    print(' lamda_s =', lamda_s)
    print('lamda_bl =', lamda_bl)
    print('  phi_bl =', phi_bl)
    print('   p_hat =', p_hat)
    print('pjs equation errors:')
    print(constrain_ps(s1, s2, s3, params))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
     p_s = 2.8526260821832463
 lamda_s = 0.1937634525070506
lamda_bl = 4.999999999999996
  phi_bl = 0.29999999999975147
   p_hat = 0.10000000000000005
pjs equation errors:
[-4.52609218e-08 -4.37312120e-08  7.77375703e-09  7.74417697e-09
 -4.52615372e-08 -4.52612817e-08  1.63845859e-09 -1.49695251e-09
  3.55849794e-10 -4.52621541e-08 -3.45946843e-08 -3.28769829e-08
 -1.17397136e-09 -1.14484833e-09 -3.45941857e-08 -3.45951420e-08
  1.15751003e-09 -3.98884203e-09 -8.80438666e-10 -3.45948470e-08
  7.98552173e-08  7.66103062e-08 -6.59930843e-09 -6.59914307e-09
  7.98556435e-08  7.98554262e-08 -2.79849960e-09  5.48236018e-09
  5.24669364e-10  7.98545330e-08]
```

Comment: We first set up start values for `p1_s` and constrain `p1_sv=p1_s` during the optimization. Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: Yes that is correct